# Using group_modify to apply function to grouped dataframe

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am trying to apply a function to each group of data in the main dataframe and I decided to use group_modify() (since it returns a dataframe as well). Here is my initial code:

```
max_conc_fx <- function(df) { 
  highest_conc <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    curr_time <- df$event_time[i]
    within1hr <- filter(df, abs(event_time - curr_time) <= hours(1))
    num_buyers <- length(unique(within1hr$userid))
    curr_conc <- nrow(within1hr)/num_buyers
    if (curr_conc > highest_conc) {
      highest_conc <- curr_conc
    }
  }
  mutate(df, highest_conc)
}

conc_data <- group_modify(data, max_conc_fx)
```

However, I keep getting this error message:

> Error in as_group_map_function(.f) : 
>     The function must accept at least two arguments. You can use ... to absorb unused components

After some trial and error, I rectified this by adding the argument "..." to my max_conc_fx() function, which leads to this code which works:

```
max_conc_fx <- function(df, ...) { #x is the rows of data for one shop
  highest_conc <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    curr_time <- df$event_time[i]
    within1hr <- filter(df, abs(event_time - curr_time) <= hours(1))
    num_buyers <- length(unique(within1hr$userid))
    curr_conc <- nrow(within1hr)/num_buyers
    if (curr_conc > highest_conc) {
      highest_conc <- curr_conc
    }
  }
  mutate(df, highest_conc)
}

conc_data <- group_modify(data, max_conc_fx)
```

Can someone explain to me what the dots are actually for in this case? I understood them to be used for representing an arbitrary number of arguments or for passing on additional arguments to  other functions, but I do not see both of these events happening here. Do let me know if I am missing out something or if you have a better solution for my code.

Answer (score 1):

The dots don't do much in that case, but there is a condition that requires them in your functions case for `group_modify()`to work. The function you are passing is getting converted using a helper function [`as_group_map_function()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/cd2350d23aab4c0d1c8e9bb24e8c5fb25dbb7e03/R/group_map.R#L2-L8). This function checks if the function has more than two arguments and if not it should have `...` to pass:

```r
## dplyr/R/group_map.R (Lines 2-8)
as_group_map_function <- function(.f) {
  .f <- rlang::as_function(.f)
  if (length(form <- formals(.f)) < 2 && ! "..." %in% names(form)){
    stop("The function must accept at least two arguments. You can use ... to absorb unused components")
  }
  .f
}
```

I'm not 100% sure why it is done, but based on a quick peek on the source code it looks like there is a point where they pass two arguments and `...` to the 'converted' version of your function (technically there is no conversion that happens – the conversion only takes place if you pass a formula instead of a function...), so my best guess is that is the reason: it needs to have some way of dealing with at least two arguments — if it doesn't need them, then it needs `...` to 'absorb' them, otherwise it would fail.