# How to replace `cur_data()` with `pick()` when adding a row to each group in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I see that in `dplyr` the function `cur_data()` has been deprecated in favor of `pick()`. However, I'm confused about how to use `pick()` when trying to add rows to each group in a grouped dataframe. I'm cleaning some funky data and need to insert rows into each group that propagate the grouping variable's value while inserting a specific value into an accompanying column.

Here's example code that uses `cur_data()` to produce my desired output:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,   ~val,
  "A",   95,
  "A",   20,
  "A",   45,
  "B",   10,
  "B",   50,
  "C",   80
)

df_new_rows <- df |>
  dplyr::group_by(id) |>
  dplyr::reframe(tibble::add_row(dplyr::cur_data(), val = 100)) |>
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Here's the desired output - the rows with `100` in the `val` column have been inserted:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  id      val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A        95
2 A        20
3 A        45
4 A       100
5 B        10
6 B        50
7 B       100
8 C        80
9 C       100
```

How can I use `pick()` or another function to do this? For development reasons I'd like to use either base `R` or `tidyverse` functions, but if there is no way to do that I'm open to other suggestions. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace cur\_dat() with pick()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77263831/how-to-replace-cur-dat-with-pick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Try `nest_by` which creates a 3 row data frame with everything except `id` in a list column `data`.

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  nest_by(id) |>
  reframe(add_row(data, val = 100))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  id      val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A        95
2 A        20
3 A        45
4 A       100
5 B        10
6 B        50
7 B       100
8 C        80
9 C       100
```

**2)** or this which gives the same output

```
df |>
  reframe(add_row(pick(everything()), val = 100), .by = id)
```

**3)** This is a base R solution. Define a function `AddRow` to add a row to one component of the split and then run `by` to perform the split and finally `do.call` with `rbind` to put it back together.

```
AddRow <- function(x, ...) rbind(x, transform(x[1, ], ...))
do.call("rbind", by(df, df$id, AddRow, val = 10))
```

**4)** This is another base R approach.  It applies if the input `df` has two columns as is the case here.  Use `tapply` to split `val` by `id` appending 10 to each resulting component.  Then use `stack` to convert to long form.  `stack` puts the `id` columns second and renames that column `ind`.  It also puts the `val` column first and renames it `values` so use `rev` to switch them around and then add the original names back.

```
df2 <- df |>  with(tapply(val, id, append, 10)) |> stack() |> rev()
names(df2) <- names(df)
df2
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [group_modify()](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/group_map.html) to applies a function to each group in a grouped tibble, and returns a grouped tibble.

```
df <- tibble::tibble(
 id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
 val = c(95, 20, 45, 10, 50, 80)
)

add_row_func <- function(df) {
 tibble::add_row(df, id = df$id[1], val = 100)
}

df_new_rows <- df |>
 dplyr::group_by(id) |>
 dplyr::group_modify(add_row_func) |>
 dplyr::ungroup()

print(df_new_rows)
```

Comment: This is great - thanks! A quick note that for `group_modify` to take a function with a single argument, the function must have `...` in its definition - so `add_row_func` should be defined as `function(df, ...)` for this to work. (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359251/using-group-modify-to-apply-function-to-grouped-dataframe)

Comment: @lucyandrews Also, `id = df$id[1]` is not needed in `add_row`.